# Why is Selenium not finding an element

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I wrote this short programm to login in to my postfield:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.web.de/')
time.sleep(2)
frame = driver.find_element_by_name('landingpage')
  # do something with frame ...
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
innerFrame = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(innerFrame)
driver.find_element_by_id("save-all-conditionally").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(3)
inputemail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/input')
inputpwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/input')
buttonsend = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/form/button')
inputemail.send_keys('xxx@web.de')
inputpwd.send_keys('xxx')
buttonsend.click()
time.sleep(3)
frame2 = driver.find_element_by_name('home')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame2)
linkwrite = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/ul/li/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/a')
linkwrite.click()
```

This part is working fine with the iframes there. My next goal was then to fill out an input field. The Code of the page which opened after the sign in progress is the one on the picture: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210919Porfd5N7
But the Code for filling:

```
frame3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('...')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame3)
fillin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/input')
fillin.send_keys('hello')
```

has resulted in:
"Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/nav/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]"}"
Where's my mistake?
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Few things

1. There are nested iframe, first one is `iframe[name='landingpage']` (located by css selector) second one is `iframe[sandbox*='allow-popups'][style^='display']` and then you can click on `Zustimmen und weiter` button.
2. The `xpath` that you are using is **absolute**, try using **relative xpath**, if possible switch to `css_selector`.
3. Use Explicit waits.

**Code :-**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://web.de/consent-management/")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name='landingpage']")))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[sandbox*='allow-popups'][style^='display']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "save-all-conditionally"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

inputemail = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "freemailLoginUsername")))
inputpwd =  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "freemailLoginPassword")))
buttonsend = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']")))
inputemail.send_keys('xxx@web.de')
inputpwd.send_keys('xxx')
buttonsend.click()
time.sleep(3)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Additionally you can use the **below code :**

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pos-input input"))).send_keys('WEB.DE E-Mail-Adresse')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pos-input input[name^='password']"))).send_keys('password here')
```

to fill details on **Bitte erneut einloggen** page.